# Why notification is saying my Facebook name messaging me when it's someone else messaging me?

Tags: notifications, facebook-messenger

So, out of nowhere, when I get notifications about someone messaging me on Facebook Messenger, it says my Facebook name is messaging me instead of the other user. But when I go to the app, it says their correct name as the person who messaged me. But when they come into my phone, it shows my Facebook name, like I messaged myself but it's them messaging me.

Could that possibly be me being hacked or is it just a system malfunction?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Could you check your phone's contacts whether it has your name with their phone number?

Comment: Are you logged into multiple accounts on the app? If nothing works clearing app data and rechecking is an option

Comment: Recovered a few gmails and had them logged on at one time for like 30 min before all this but after 30 min went straight to only E gmails that I'm logged into now.